# Return a page when no internet connection instead of toast

Tags: flutter

I'm building flutter app and I created a function that checks the internet  connection, if there is no internet connection it should show me a page (created Internet() page here) with message "failed to connect try again..", i tried here to route to internet page in below if statement but it didn't work. However, it works with toast perfectly, any help?

ps:it throws " The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget."

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io'; //InternetAddress utility
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

  runApp(
   
      child: Notification(),
  );


class Notification extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationState createState() => _NotificationState();
}

class _NotificationState extends State<Notification> {
  var subscription;
  var connectionStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {         
        setState(() => connectionStatus = result);
        checkInternetConnectivity();
});
    
    
    super.initState();
  }

   checkInternetConnectivity() {
 if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (_) => Internet())),
      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
    ),
  );
}}


  // checkInternetConnectivity() {
  //   if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  //     return 
 
  //     Fluttertoast.showToast(
  //         msg: "Check your internet connection",
        
  //         toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
  //         gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
  //         timeInSecForIosWeb: 10,
  //         backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  //         textColor: Colors.white,
  //         fontSize: 16.0
  //     );
  //   }
  // }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }
  
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return MaterialApp(
          
          home: MyHomePage(),

          localizationsDelegates:
              translator.delegates,
          locale: translator.locale, // Active locale
          supportedLocales: translator.locals(),

    
  
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        
         
        ),
        }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  Looks like you have the full code here. 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback).   Can you narrow down the problem with the code please

Comment: thank u, i already represented Minimal, Reproducible code,my problem is in if statement, it didn't take me to the specified page when there is no connection also i mentioned error throws above in "PS"

Answer (score 0):

You're not navigating. Use this instead:

```
if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (_) => Internet())),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

And if you don't want to show any kind of route animation, use this:

```
if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (_) => Internet())),
      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried both of ur answers but it didn't work, the app wifi is turned off and it's supposed to take me to internet page but it opens app normal home screen :/

Comment: you mean smth u can run?

Comment: @sara97 Yes, something I can run locally with minimal code.

Comment: @sara97 Sorry, your code has compile time errors, for instance your `runApp` method takes `child` as an argument but in Dart, this method has positional parameters and not named. Can you post a correct (minimal reproducible code)?